# error converting string to bigdecimal

Tags: java, parsing, bigdecimal

Goodmorning,
I'm parsing a string to a big decimal but the debugger returns an error when i set the pattern ans simbols to it. The code is very simple and i've taken it from the documentation and from an other post here on stackoverflow which i don't remember what address it is. It is below:

```
DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
    symbols.setGroupingSeparator('.');
    symbols.setDecimalSeparator(',');
    String pattern = "#.##0,0#";
    DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat(pattern, symbols);
    decimalFormat.setParseBigDecimal(true);

(BigDecimal) decimalFormat.parse(entity.getQta()))
```

the error is thrown at this line:

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat(pattern, symbols);
```

StackTrace of GWT debugger:

```
com.smartgwt.client.core.JsObject$SGWT_WARN: 

09:29:12.673:MOU6:WARN:RPCManager:ATTENZIONE: si e' verificato un errore imprevisto [SC: 500]undefined - response: {clientContext: Obj,
status: -1,
invalidateCache: true,
data: "ATTENZIONE: si e' verificato un errore i..."[59],
internalClientContext: Obj,
context: undef,
startRow: 0,
endRow: 0,
totalRows: 0}   at 
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)   at  
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)    at 
 sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)   at 
 java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)    at 
 com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:105)  at 
 com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)     at 
 com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)  at 
  com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:338)     at 
 com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:219)  at 
  com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)     at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:576)  at 
com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeVoid(ModuleSpace.java:304)     at 
 com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeVoid(JavaScriptHost.java:107)  at com.smartgwt.client.data.DataSource.processResponse(DataSource.java)     at 
com.sgss.common.client.ds.SgssGwtRpcDataSource.handleFailure(SgssGwtRpcDataSource.java:205)     at 
 com.sgss.common.client.ds.SgssGwtRpcDataSource$GenericAsyncCallback.onFailure(SgssGwtRpcDataSource.java:148)   at 
 com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.RequestCallbackAdapter.onResponseReceived(RequestCallbackAdapter.java:237)     at 
com.google.gwt.http.client.Request.fireOnResponseReceived(Request.java:259)     at 
com.google.gwt.http.client.RequestBuilder$1.onReadyStateChange(RequestBuilder.java:412)     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor417.invoke(Unknown Source)    at 
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at 
 com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)  at 
 com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)     at 
 com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)  at 
 com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:338)  at 
 com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:219)  at 
 com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)  at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:576)  at 
 com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:284)  at 
 com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)     at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)    at 
 com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:356)     at 
 sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor412.invoke(Unknown Source)  at 
 sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at 
  com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)     at 
 com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)     at 
 com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)  at 
 com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:293)   at 
  com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:547)    at 
 com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:364)   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

EDIT:I didn't metioned GWT (SMartGwt in my case, cause i'm doing this parsing in the backend, which doesn't use smartgwt but only spring and hibernate.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], which should include the value you're trying to parse, and your default FORMAT locale.

Comment: Just post the error message along with your question.

Comment: @Jon Skeet entity.getQta() is a String like 1.743.711,67 and the locale is it_IT

Comment: @Jon Skeet but what difference does it make, the execution never reaches the point where i'm parsing the value

Comment: Then your minimal example doesn't need to include that. (I'd missed that line of your post, to be honest.) The fact that you hadn't even *mentioned* GWT before is worrying - please give more context here, and reformat the stack trace to be more readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pattern is incorrect, in the line:

```
String pattern = "#.##0,0#";
```

according to the documentation 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html (in the section titled **Special Pattern Characters**) the "," sign in the pattern is reserves for the grouping separator - not literally the comma in the number; the "." is reserved for the decimal separator, not literally the point character.

Since your numbers are in the format 1.743.711,67 (and not 1,743,711.67), you used the symbols variable to designate "," as the decimal separator and the "." as the grouping separator. However, the pattern doesn't follow the same logic. It swaps the locations of the grouping and decimal separators so it fails.

I would suggest you try:

```
String pattern = "#,##0.0#";
```

With the same code and see if it helps.

Comment: If it helped you, could you kindly accept the answer? If not, let me know and I'll try and help.